# how to use MessageBox in C# , i tried to used its button parameter

Tags: c#

I try to write like this :

```
MessageBox.Show("Request is Online process!", "callback ,tips",MessageBoxButton.OKCancel)
```

But it said there is 'no MessageBoxButton exist in the context`

How can i solve this ?

Comment: What kind of project are you working with? Windows forms, WPF, Silverlight, etc ...

Comment: i am sorry @gnat, i am just here so i didn't notice what category my question is about .really sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that there are both Winforms APIs and WPF APIs in C#, you have to make sure you are referencing the version you think you are.  For many things like MessageBox, the API is similar, but just different enough to cause problems.

- [Winforms MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -- package System.Windows.Forms
- [WPF MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -- package System.Windows

One of the similar but incompatible difference is that the Winforms MessageBox has an enumeration called `MessageBoxButtons` (note the s on the end) and the WPF version has an enumeration called `MessageBoxButton`.

What's happening is that you are using the Winforms version and wrote your code against the WPF version.  Since they have the same name, it's probably due to your `using` statements.

To disambiguate when you can't remove using statements, use the explicit using statement:

```
using MessageBox = System.Windows.MessageBox;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks Berin ,you really help me and i have solved the problem as you said. i am working on windforms and it's incompatible.thanks for your detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`MessageBox.Show("A header", "Your msg", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);`

Also there are lots of Buttons to use, to view them you can write `MessageBoxButtons.`

and let intellisensedo the rest for you.

Comment: thanks Magar , have solved .it's because i am using conflicting namespace.  windforms messagebox ---system.windows.forms.WPF messagebox ---system.windows   two different messagebox namespaces